# Drawing a spiral in Java

Tags: java, drawing

Basically I'm looking to draw a spiral by taking 4 point arrays, one in each corner of the frame, and having them follow each other in a counter-clockwise direction until they reach the center. The points move forward in a straight line, but their x- and y- positions change in proportion to the distance between them at each time step.

Trying to find out how to keep the arrays within bounds of the screen. Nothing is showing up.

Please let me know if you have an idea of where to go from here. All help is greatly appreciated. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Slugs extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Lines update for 1000 ticks
    final int max = 1000;

    //Initial seed
    public int i = 0;

    //Translates each point into an array value
    final double[][][] points = new double[4][2][];

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //Creates scanner object for file output name
        Scanner console = new Scanner(new File("slug_details.txt"));

        //Creates scanner object for edge and node values
        String edge = console.nextLine();
        Scanner console1 = new Scanner(edge);

        //Scans input file for all values
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String file = console1.next();
        int width = console1.nextInt();
        int d = console1.nextInt();

        //Creates frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        //Sets frame size
        frame.setSize(width, width);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Slugs panel = new Slugs(frame.getWidth(), d);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public Slugs(final int width, int d) {

        //Sets up the array
        for (int edge = 0; edge < points.length; edge++) {
            for (int node = 0; node < points[edge].length; node++) {
                points[edge][node] = new double[max];
            }
        }

        //Top-left corner
        points[0][0][0] = 0;
        points[0][1][0] = 0;

        //Bottom-left corner
        points[1][0][0] = 0;
        points[1][1][0] = width;

        //Bottom-right corner
        points[2][0][0] = width;
        points[2][1][0] = width;

        //Top-right corner
        points[3][0][0] = width;
        points[3][1][0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {

            for (int edge = 0; edge < points.length; edge++) {

                //Updates subsequent vector positions
                final double vectX = points[(edge + 1) % 4][0][i - 1]
                        - points[edge][0][i - 1];
                final double vectY = points[(edge + 1) % 4][1][i - 1]
                        - points[edge][1][i - 1];

                //Get vector length
                final double length = hypot(vectX, vectY);

                //Constrain vector length by screen bounds
                final double deltaX = vectX;
                final double deltaY = vectY;

                //Save current point
                points[edge][0][i] = points[edge][0][i - 1] + deltaX;
                points[edge][1][i] = points[edge][1][i - 1] + deltaY;
            }
        }
    }

    //Draws the algorithm
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (i < max - 1) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            for (int edge = 0; edge < points.length; edge++) {
                g.drawLine((int) points[edge][0][i], (int) points[edge][1][i], (int) points[edge][0][i + 1], (int) points[edge][1][i + 1]);
            }

            i++;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

    //Formula for the distance between two points
    static double hypot(double a, double b) {
        return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    }
```

Comment: A more mathematical approach to generating the points, perhaps could be looked at, refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute for equation of an involute, or more generally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral for spirals, choose the required parametric equation and for different values of the parameters calculate and generate the x,y values and plot

Comment: please state what your problem is with the code you already have. Why is it not working for you? Be more specific on where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for...good look on explaining to your professor that you figured it out on your own but for what it's worth, it was fun generating the nice spiral pattern.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Spiral extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static final int WIDTH = 500;

    public static final double PIX_RES = 3;
    public static final double WEIGHT = PIX_RES / WIDTH;

    public static final long SLEEP_TIME = 10;

    private final GeneralPath topRight = new GeneralPath();
    private final GeneralPath topLeft = new GeneralPath();
    private final GeneralPath bottomLeft = new GeneralPath();
    private final GeneralPath bottomRight = new GeneralPath();

    public Spiral(){
        this(WIDTH);
    }

    public Spiral(final int width) {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
        topRight.moveTo(width, 0);
        topLeft.moveTo(0, 0);
        bottomLeft.moveTo(0, width);
        bottomRight.moveTo(width, width);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(topLeft);
        g2.draw(topRight);
        g2.draw(bottomLeft);
        g2.draw(bottomRight);
    }

    /**
     * generated by eclipse
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -756842929825603438L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            iterate();
            this.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void iterate() {
        final double dx = topRight.getCurrentPoint().getX()
                - topLeft.getCurrentPoint().getX();
        final double dy = -topRight.getCurrentPoint().getY()
                + topLeft.getCurrentPoint().getY();
        final Point2D pTR = topRight.getCurrentPoint();
        final Point2D pTL = topLeft.getCurrentPoint();
        final Point2D pBL = bottomLeft.getCurrentPoint();
        final Point2D pBR = bottomRight.getCurrentPoint();

        topRight.lineTo(pTR.getX() - dx * WEIGHT, pTR.getY() + dy * WEIGHT);
        topLeft.lineTo(pTL.getX() + dy * WEIGHT, pTL.getY() + dx * WEIGHT);
        bottomRight.lineTo(pBR.getX() - dy * WEIGHT, pBR.getY() - dx * WEIGHT);
        bottomLeft.lineTo(pBL.getX() + dx * WEIGHT, pBL.getY() - dy * WEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("spiral");

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // who cares
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final Spiral spiral = new Spiral();

        frame.setContentPane(spiral);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        (new Thread(spiral)).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called a "pursuit curve". I've modified your program to demonstrate the effect.

[image: Generated pursuit curve spiral]

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Slugs extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Max length of line segment.
    final double range = 1;

    // Total number of iterations of the algorithm.
    final int num = 2000;

    // current iteration
    public int i = 0;

    // Declare arrays for points.
    final double[][][] points = new double[4][2][];

    public Slugs (final int width, final int height) {

        // initialize arrays for points.
        for (int line = 0; line < points.length; line++)
        {
            for (int axis = 0; axis < points[line].length; axis++)
            {
                points[line][axis] = new double[num];
            }
        }

        // First point placed in center of panel.
        points[0][0][0] = 100;
        points[0][1][0] = 100;

        points[1][0][0] = 100;
        points[1][1][0] = 700;

        points[2][0][0] = 700;
        points[2][1][0] = 700;

        points[3][0][0] = 700;
        points[3][1][0] = 100;

        // Generate a random point.
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            // for each line
            for (int line = 0; line < points.length; line++) {

                // calculate vector from last point on this line to last point
                // on the line we're chasing
                final double vectX =
                    points[(line + 1) % 4][0][i - 1] - points[line][0][i - 1];
                final double vectY =
                    points[(line + 1) % 4][1][i - 1] - points[line][1][i - 1];

                // find length of the vector
                final double length = hypot(vectX, vectY);

                // adjust vector length to max allowable range
                final double deltaX = vectX / length * range;
                final double deltaY = vectY / length * range;

                // record current point
                points[line][0][i] = points[line][0][i - 1] + deltaX;
                points[line][1][i] = points[line][1][i - 1] + deltaY;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if(i < num - 1) { 

            g.setColor(Color.blue);

            for (int line = 0; line < points.length; line++)
            {
                g.drawLine(
                    (int) points[line][0][i],     (int) points[line][1][i],
                    (int) points[line][0][i + 1], (int) points[line][1][i + 1]);
            }

            i++;
            delay(0);

            // sketchy recursion. If num is too high the program will crash
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Generates frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // Sets frame resolution and other frame parameters.
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Slugs panel = new Slugs(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    //Defines speed of delay between ticks.
    public static void delay(long milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // hypotenuse length
    static double hypot(double a, double b)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    }
}
```